# Root index and subscript placement with STIX Two Math Font (Lualatex)

Tags: math-mode, xetex, luatex, stix

The index spacing is somewhat problematic in STIX Two Math (v2.1) font. It is most evident with the root index, but subscripts are a little to close to the main symbol in my opinion, too. Exponents feel that way, as well. But especially those root indices...

Is there a way to improve it by a setting while loading the font or by other means?

A minimal working example:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\begin{document}
    
    \( \sqrt[q]{a^p} P_k\)
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See github.com/stipub/stixfonts/issues/222. This is problem of Stix Two Math under XeLaTeX. Positioning of subscript is correct with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Don't know about XeLaTeX, but after your comment I checked again: (using Texlive 2021 and also Texlive 2022, fully updated). Unfortunately, the problems illustrated in the picture produced by the tex markup in the question remain. It is probably neither Lualatex nor xetex (not sure about the latter) but a font issue, I never used xelatex for anything anyways.

Comment: @balcibus: I tested XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX with StixTwo under MikTeX. My book under LuaLaTeX gets few pages shorter than under XeLaTeX. In both cases StixTwo was used. As I wroted earlier positioning of subscripts under XeLaTeX was annoying.

Comment: Using  lualatex version `LuaHBTeX, Version 1.14.0 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)` , just redownloaded STIX2, the problem is still there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked,

> Is there a way to improve it by a setting while loading the font or by other means?

I'm not aware of ways to fix the issues you've identified at font loading time.

The `amsmath` package provides the directives `\uproot` and `\leftroot` to tweak the placement of the root index.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\uproot' and '\leftroot' directives
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}
$\sqrt[q]{a^p} P_k$ vs.\ 
$\sqrt[\uproot{3}\leftroot{-3}q]{a^p} P^{}_k$
\end{document}
```

Comment: From your suggestion, today, I've learnt `\uproot` and `\leftroot`, thanks a lot... to be frank, till date, I didn't know about these...(feel shame on me...). :-(

Comment: See https://github.com/stipub/stixfonts/issues/222. This is problem of Stix Two Math under XeLaTeX. Positioning of subscript is correct with LuaLaTeX. Version 2.20 of Stix Two is expected soon.

Comment: no. The problem happens also with lualatex. I tested it in different environments. I also tested using *overleaf* , they use `LuaHBTeX, Version 1.16.0 (TeX Live 2023)`  , it is still wrong